# Alternative to nested for-loop in Julia

Tags: for-loop, iteration, julia

Given arbitrary integers a and b, I want to create a list of all different pairs within Z_a^b \times Z_a^b. For example, taking a=3 and b=2, I want to have an array

```
[[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,1]],[[0,0],[0,2]],...,[[2,2],[2,1]],[[2,2],[2,2]]]
```

I want to do this within Julia. However, I do not know how to do this easily for arbitrary values of b (even for fixed b, the only way I can think to do this would be nested for loops). Is there a quick way of implementing this?

Comment: Have you tried with `Iterators.product`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> Z(a, b) = Iterators.product([0:a-1 for _ in 1:b]...)
Z (generic function with 1 method)

julia> collect(Iterators.product(Z(3,2), Z(3,2))) |> vec
81-element Vector{Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}:
 ((0, 0), (0, 0))
 ((1, 0), (0, 0))
 ((2, 0), (0, 0))
 ((0, 1), (0, 0))
 ((1, 1), (0, 0))
 ((2, 1), (0, 0))
 ((0, 2), (0, 0))
 ((1, 2), (0, 0))
 ((2, 2), (0, 0))
 ((0, 0), (1, 0))
 ⋮
 ((0, 0), (2, 2))
 ((1, 0), (2, 2))
 ((2, 0), (2, 2))
 ((0, 1), (2, 2))
 ((1, 1), (2, 2))
 ((2, 1), (2, 2))
 ((0, 2), (2, 2))
 ((1, 2), (2, 2))
 ((2, 2), (2, 2))

julia> collect(Iterators.product(Z(4,3), Z(4,3))) |> vec
4096-element Vector{Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}}:
 ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
 ((1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
 ((2, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
 ((3, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
 ((0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0))
 ((1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0))
 ((2, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0))
 ((3, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0))
 ((0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 0))
 ((1, 2, 0), (0, 0, 0))
 ⋮
 ((3, 1, 3), (3, 3, 3))
 ((0, 2, 3), (3, 3, 3))
 ((1, 2, 3), (3, 3, 3))
 ((2, 2, 3), (3, 3, 3))
 ((3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 3))
 ((0, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3))
 ((1, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3))
 ((2, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3))
 ((3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3))
```

Note that I `collect` it to make the result visible. Normally, as the result set can be very large it is better to stay with lazy `Iterators.product` and just iterate it.

Comment: Thank you. The case with a=4 and b=3 appears to be seems to be off, though. Am I mistaken to say that it should always be in tuples of two integers? For example, for a=3 and b=3, it should be 

((0,0),(0,0),(0,0))
((0,0),(0,0),(0,1))

etc. For a=4 and b=3, I'd expect something similar, but now the values of the integers can be 0,1,2, or 3.

Comment: Elements of Z_a^b are b-tupes, and if you are taking a product of two b-tuples you get a 2-tuple containing two b-tuples. If you want to convert 2-tuple of b-tuples to b-tuple containing 2-tuples you can use the `invert` function from SplitApplyCombine.jl package.